# Find all possible distances from two arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given two sorted array `A` and `B` length N. Each elements may contain natural number less than `M`. Determine all possible distances for all combinations elements `A` and `B`. In this case, if `A[i] - B[j] < 0`, then the distance is `M + (A[i] - B[j])`.

Example :

```
A = {0,2,3}
B = {1,2}
M = 5

Distances = {0,1,2,3,4}
```

Note: I know `O(N^2)` solution, but I need faster solution than `O(N^2)` and `O(N x M)`.

Edit: Array `A`, `B`, and `Distances` contain distinct elements.

Comment: The distances may contain no duplicates.

Comment: I dont think that you'll find better than 0(MxN)  but Im expecting someone to post anything, it would be interesting :)

Comment: Considering the output can be `N * M` values, I don't think we can write an algorithm faster then O(N * M).

Comment: @appzYourLife, looking at the question the number of unique outputs is bounded by M.

Comment: What is max(M)? and array sizes N ?

Comment: You can do an O(M²) ??

Comment: @vish4071, assume the maximum value of M and the size of array N is 50000 and we try to solve in under 1~2 seconds.

Comment: @yahyaelfakir no, but even if it's possible, it still isn't fast enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a O(MlogM) complexity solution in the following way.

1. Prepare an array Ax of length M with Ax[i] = 1 if i belongs to A (and 0 otherwise)
2. Prepare an array Bx of length M with Bx[M-1-i] = 1 if i belongs to B (and 0 otherwise)
3. Use the Fast Fourier Transform to convolve these 2 sequences together
4. Inspect the output array, non-zero values correspond to possible distances

Note that the FFT is normally done with floating point numbers, so in step 4 you probably want to test if the output is greater than 0.5 to avoid potential rounding noise issues.

Comment: What is the size of results into step #3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mr. Peter. I will accept this answer when I manage to confirm it. Currently, I'm not fully understand FFT yet. I will be very happy if you give reference about related FFT algorithm.

Comment: This is trivial if you use Python with the scipy library because there is a function [fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) that does step 3 for you in one line :)

Comment: @Толя You get 2*M-1 outputs, 1 for the case when A[i]-B[i]=0, then M-1 for the cases with A[i]<B[i], and M-1 for the cases with A[i]>B[i].  In fact the count in the output array gives exactly the number of different ways of making each case.

Answer (score 0):

I possible done with optimized N*N.

If convert A to 0 and 1 array where 1 on positions which present in A (in range [0..M].
After convert this array into bitmasks, size of A array will be decreased into 64 times.

This will allow insert results by blocks of size 64.
Complexity still will be `N*N` but working time will be greatly decreased. As limitation mentioned by author 50000 for A and B sizes and M.
**Expected operations count will be N*N/64 ~= 4*10^7. It will passed in 1 sec.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitvectors to accomplish this. Bitvector operations on large bitvectors is linear in the size of the bitvector, but is fast, easy to implement, and may work well given your 50k size limit.

Initialize two bitvectors of length M. Call these vectA and vectAnswer. Set the bits of vectA that correspond to the elements in A. Leave vectAnswer with all zeroes.

Define a method to rotate a bitvector by k elements (rotate down). I'll call this rotate(vect,k).

Then, for every element b of B, vectAnswer = vectAnswer | rotate(vectA,b).